# How to return Map from Callable Future function in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, future, callable

In my spring boot program I am trying to use **Callable Future** function for multiprocessing. To be more precise Inside *loop* I opened multiple threads and receiving List of Map from function. After that I am printing the result I received. Unfortunately it is giving error `Method threw 'java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException' exception`. Inside detailed message `NullPointerException`. I tried multiple ways which none of them working.

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<List<Map<String, Object>>> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcMaster")
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private String SQL_QUERY;

    public MyCallable(){
    }

    public MyCallable(String SQL_QUERY){
        this.SQL_QUERY = SQL_QUERY;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, Object>> call() throws Exception {
        List<Map<String, Object>> ph_list = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL_QUERY);
        return ph_list;
    }
}
```

```
        Integer listSize = regionFilials.size();
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(listSize);
        List<Future<List<Map<String, Object>>>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++){
            filialId = "'" + regionFilials.get(i) + "'";
            SQL_RESULT = SQL_SPECIAL_INCOME.replace("?", filialId);

            MyCallable myCallable  = new MyCallable(SQL_RESULT);
            Future<List<Map<String, Object>>> result = service.submit(myCallable);
            resultList.add(result);
        }

       for (Future<List<Map<String, Object>>> futures : resultList){

           try {
               if (futures.isDone()) {
                   try {
                       System.out.println("Name: " + futures.get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
                   } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }

           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (ExecutionException e) {
               e.getCause();
           }

       }
```

When I try to get result of SQL_RESULT select statement with ordinary way, it is giving proper result. Problem is not with SQL. I suppose whether I am catching future result incorrectly or implementing callable future in wrong way.

Comment: could you put here the stack trace? I also recommend you to run the code without concurrency to make sure the problem is not caused by some other problem in the logic, i.e. db response is different from what you expect

Comment: Actually it is not giving error. When I put debug on line ``` futures.get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ```  and see Evaluate Expression in the result field it is showing above error.

Comment: did you try to increase the timeout, i.e. put futures.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS) or, just use futures.get()?

Comment: I used both timout and without timeout version. Both of them are not working

Comment: but if you run without futurs and concurrency, do you get the expected result?

Comment: yes, I got expected result

Comment: Seems to be interesting, just a guess, does MyCallable have annotation? is jdbcTemplate dependecy properly injected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see MyCallable has no annotations and besides it is not instantiated by Spring, so that means jdbcTemplate dependency will not be auto-injected. Please check in debug - it should be null.
I recommend one of the following options:

1. Add JdbcTemplate dependency to the class where you create callables. Set JdbcTemplate in the constructor of MyCallable or create a setter for JdbcTemplate and set it manually.
2. Leave it as is, just make sure you have @Component annotation and @Scope set to prototype for MyCallable. Then you can use context.getBean(MyCallable.class) to instantiate MyCallable with JDBCTemplate injected.

I would recommend the first approach as there's no much sence in MyCallable as bean - it is not injected anywhere so the second approach is not common and makes the code not so clean.

Comment: Yes you are right jdbcTemplate is null when I check in debug

Comment: Now it is working. First way you recommended worked. Thank you for help. Appreciate it!